# Unable to load the requested class: Config

Tags: php

I am getting an error in Code Igniter as the following:

> "Unable to load the requested class: Config."

I am trying to auto-load the word `config` into code igniter's

```
application->config->autoload.php
```

I am using windows os and not Linux, so it would seem that capitalization would not matter. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: though in windows try to match the  name

Comment: The only file that is named "config" is the config.php in code igniter's application file.